# What is the difference with using the 'dot' in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, javascript-framework, prototypal-inheritance

Here are two snippets of code:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data.message">
<div>Hello, {{data.message}}</div>

<div ng-controller="firstCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="data.message">
    <div>Hello, {{data.message}}</div>
</div>

<div ng-controller="secondCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="data.message">
    <div>Hello, {{data.message}}</div>
</div>
```

and

```
<input type="text" ng-model="msg">
<div>Hello, {{msg}}</div>

<div ng-controller="firstCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="msg">
    <div>Hello, {{msg}}</div>
</div>

<div ng-controller="secondCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="msg">
    <div>Hello, {{msg}}</div>
</div>
```

`ng-controller` here creates new scope so the `firstCtrl` and `secondCtrl` scope prototypically inherits from root scope in both cases. So, ideally, when the property of a children is overwritten is `shadows` the inherited value from parent and the value in parent stays same. **Then why do the two snippets work differently?**

Also, why in the first snippet, changing the value in `firstCtrl` changes the value in root scope as well?

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/x4LH4JAOMr9I8bCcSO8Y?p=preview

Comment: This should answer all your questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs?rq=1

Comment: Root scope is changed because firstCtrl prototypically inherits from root scope.  Since firstCtrl is modifying an object property, it checks the prototype chain and finds the object in the $rootScope, so it gets modified there.

Comment: Thanks! The two comments above clear my doubt!

Answer (score 1):

The `dot` is used to sync the controllers so updating a property in one model will cause the property in the other controllers to be updated too.

In your second snippet you are overwriting the scope.

please see [this](http://www.egghead.io/video/DTx23w4z6Kc) video which explains it nicely.

Comment: What I wanted to know was why is the behavior like that? This explains it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs?rq=1